# Total reinstall of Windows 10 when the OS is unreliable

Tags: windows-10

I got an ASUS machine with Window 10 on it last year, and somehow during one of the updates something went wrong and the whole thing is SUPER unreliable now. Basically any attempts at repairing or updating or rolling back the updates fail, because various services mysteriously fail.

There is nothing on this machine I need to keep; the whole thing can be burnt to the ground and reinstalled. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

When I try to reinstall from USB media created with the Media Creation Tool, it gives me an unspecified error. When I try to restore from a previous point, it gives me an unspecified error. When I say, reinstall Windows, delete everything, it just reboots. Clearly something fundamental is screwed up, and every option that tries to use Windows 10 to reinstall/repair/reset itself is failing.

I can get into the BIOS and I can boot from a USB. I cannot boot into Windows 10 itself — it starts to crash almost immediately, and nothing at all works (not the Start Menu, not the Task Manager, NOTHING). I cannot even get the Command Line to load from the repair boot menu — when I click it, it just resets the machine.

What do I need to do to kill this thing with fire, so that I can create a totally fresh installation? Two hours of Googling and I'm not any closer, just a lot of things I've already tried. I'm so annoyed with it and as I said there is literally zero reason to preserve any of the data.

What I'm imagining needs to be done is that I've got to essentially delete the existing partitions and just start fresh. What's the best way to do that? Or is this not the best way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me. Are there any diagnostic tools in the bios you can run??

Comment: When you install from USB, can you reformat the Windows partition and install to it?

Comment: Model of Asus??

Comment: Please expand your question and include the model and make of your hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to reinstall from USB media created with the Media Creation
> Tool, it gives me an unspecified error.

This tool should work reliably to reinstall Windows 10 fresh.

(1) Get the ASUS Diagnostics tool on a bootable USB key and check the hardware. You could have a disk error.

(2) Make another download of the Media Creation tool and try a fresh install of Windows 10 again.

Based on your description, I lean toward a hardware error.